# Last Step On configuring Magento REST and oAuth settings

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I am configuring Magento REST API and oAuth settings. But I am stuck in last step, access permissions. The radio button rest role is not showing on clicking rest role tab on left side.

[image]